# Tkinter Listbox with Entry

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, tkinter-entry

Is there a way to have the items of a Tkinter Listbox be Entry Widgets? The result would be that you could dynamically modify the text in an Listbox entry. If your Listbox looks like:

```
 --------
| Apples  |
| Pears   |
| Oranges |
 ---------
```

then you would want to be able to click on Apples and write some arbitrary text - you could then bind the Enter key, say, to trigger a function based on the new text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could give the user some entries then create a listbox from that input

but you cant just change a listboxes text like that

maybe try a different GUI Library like WX

**EDIT**

here is something you can do:

```
from Tkinter import *


root = Tk()
opt_list = ['opt1','opt2','opt3','opt4','opt5']
sel_list = []

def get_sel():
    sel_list.append(Lb1.curselection())
    root.destroy()

def change_opt():
    entry = E.get()
    change = entry.split(" ")
    print change
    Lb1.insert(int(change[0]),change[1])
    root.update()


def cancel():
    root.destroy()
E = Entry(root)
A = Button(root, text ="Change", command = change_opt)
B = Button(root, text ="Submit", command = get_sel)
C = Button(root, text ="Cancel", command = cancel)
Lb1 = Listbox(root, selectmode=MULTIPLE)


for i,j in enumerate(opt_list):
    Lb1.insert(i,j)


Lb1.pack()
B.pack()
C.pack()
E.pack()
A.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

this will make a listbox with the options in `opt_list` then when you type for example `5 hello` the entry and press Change it will add the option `hello` to the fifth place

thats the only way i can think of

Comment: This is what I assumed, but I'll have the itch until I see why not - does it say this somewhere?

Comment: hmm i dont think it is really written anywhere its more of like Tk isnt advanced enough to do that kind of thing... ill look around though

Comment: This is what I had (more or less), but if the listbox was far away from the entries it was slow to click back and forth, and if it was right next to them it looked messy. Not a big deal, and this style is a pretty good way of writing the solution. Thanks!

Comment: you can edit the layout i just typed that up real quick from some code i had glad i could help:)

Answer (score 6):

I know it has been a while since this question, but I have created a widget called 'ListboxEditable', which is able to act as a listbox and, when double-clicking on an item, the user can type anything inside an entry. Then, when the user clicks another row, the information is saved on the corresponding modified cell. Note that the user can use the up and down keys to browse the entire given list (the selected row has a different background color).

This code has been developed based on the answer from @Bryan Oakley.

## Minimal working case

```
# Imports
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
# Import for the listboxEditable
from ListboxEditable import *

# Colors
colorActiveTab="#CCCCCC" # Color of the active tab
colorNoActiveTab="#EBEBEB" # Color of the no active tab
# Fonts
fontLabels='Calibri'
sizeLabels2=13

# Main window
root = Tk()

# *** Design *****
frame_name=Frame(root,bg=colorActiveTab) # Column frame
frame_name_label=Frame(frame_name,bg='blue') # Label frame
label_name=Label(frame_name_label, text="Header", bg='blue', fg='white', font=(fontLabels, sizeLabels2, 'bold'), pady=2, padx=2, width=10)
frame_name_listbox=Frame(frame_name,bg='blue') # Label frame
list_name=['test1','test2','test3']
listBox_name=ListboxEditable(frame_name_listbox,list_name)

# *** Packing ****
frame_name.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
frame_name_label.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
label_name.pack(side=LEFT,fill=X)
frame_name_listbox.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
listBox_name.placeListBoxEditable()

# Infinite loop
root.mainloop()
```

## ListboxEditable class

```
# Author: David Duran Perez
# Date: May 26, 2017

# Necessary imports
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

# Colors
colorActiveTab="#CCCCCC" # Color of the active tab
colorNoActiveTab="#EBEBEB" # Color of the no active tab
# Fonts
fontLabels='Calibri'
sizeLabels2=13

class ListboxEditable(object):
    """A class that emulates a listbox, but you can also edit a field"""
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self,frameMaster,list):
        # *** Assign the first variables ***
        # The frame that contains the ListboxEditable
        self.frameMaster=frameMaster
        # List of the initial items
        self.list=list
        # Number of initial rows at the moment
        self.numberRows=len(self.list)

        # *** Create the necessary labels ***
        ind=1
        for row in self.list:
            # Get the name of the label
            labelName='label'+str(ind)
            # Create the variable
            setattr(self, labelName, Label(self.frameMaster, text=self.list[ind-1], bg=colorActiveTab, fg='black', font=(fontLabels, sizeLabels2), pady=2, padx=2, width=10))

            # ** Bind actions
            # 1 left click - Change background
            getattr(self, labelName).bind('<Button-1>',lambda event, a=labelName: self.changeBackground(a))
            # Double click - Convert to entry
            getattr(self, labelName).bind('<Double-1>',lambda event, a=ind: self.changeToEntry(a))
            # Move up and down
            getattr(self, labelName).bind("<Up>",lambda event, a=ind: self.up(a))
            getattr(self, labelName).bind("<Down>",lambda event, a=ind: self.down(a))

            # Increase the iterator
            ind=ind+1

    # Place
    def placeListBoxEditable(self):
        # Go row by row placing it
        ind=1
        for row in self.list:
            # Get the name of the label
            labelName='label'+str(ind)
            # Place the variable
            getattr(self, labelName).grid(row=ind-1,column=0)

            # Increase the iterator
            ind=ind+1


    # Action to do when one click
    def changeBackground(self,labelNameSelected):
        # Ensure that all the remaining labels are deselected
        ind=1
        for row in self.list:
            # Get the name of the label
            labelName='label'+str(ind)
            # Place the variable
            getattr(self, labelName).configure(bg=colorActiveTab)

            # Increase the iterator
            ind=ind+1

        # Change the background of the corresponding label
        getattr(self, labelNameSelected).configure(bg=colorNoActiveTab)
        # Set the focus for future bindings (moves)
        getattr(self, labelNameSelected).focus_set()


    # Function to do when up button pressed
    def up(self, ind):
        if ind==1: # Go to the last
            # Get the name of the label
            labelName='label'+str(self.numberRows)
        else: # Normal
            # Get the name of the label
            labelName='label'+str(ind-1)

        # Call the select
        self.changeBackground(labelName)


    # Function to do when down button pressed
    def down(self, ind):
        if ind==self.numberRows: # Go to the last
            # Get the name of the label
            labelName='label1'
        else: # Normal
            # Get the name of the label
            labelName='label'+str(ind+1)

        # Call the select
        self.changeBackground(labelName)


    # Action to do when double-click
    def changeToEntry(self,ind):
        # Variable of the current entry
        self.entryVar=StringVar()
        # Create the entry
        #entryName='entry'+str(ind) # Name
        self.entryActive=ttk.Entry(self.frameMaster, font=(fontLabels, sizeLabels2), textvariable=self.entryVar, width=10)
        # Place it on the correct grid position
        self.entryActive.grid(row=ind-1,column=0)
        # Focus to the entry
        self.entryActive.focus_set()

        # Bind the action of focusOut
        self.entryActive.bind("<FocusOut>",lambda event, a=ind: self.saveEntryValue(a))

    
    # Action to do when focus out from the entry
    def saveEntryValue(self,ind):
        # Find the label to recover
        labelName='label'+str(ind)
        # Remove the entry from the screen
        self.entryActive.grid_forget()
        # Place it again
        getattr(self, labelName).grid(row=ind-1,column=0)
        # Change the name to the value of the entry
        getattr(self, labelName).configure(text=self.entryVar.get())
```

## Some sreenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know its been years - but, you made the `ListBoxEditable` a subclass of `object` instead of `Frame`. I have seen this before, but curious why? If I want to use this class, how do I use `pack` or `grid` to place it in the master frame? Is it as easy as changing the declaration to `class ListboxEditable(Frame)` instead of `class ListboxEditable(object):`? I apologize if this is a stupid question - I am new here.

Comment: @lukehawk, in this case, the listbox I created had a method to place it called 'placeListBoxEditable()'. You just have to call it when you want to place it. It is based on a grid system.

Comment: I made a fork at https://github.com/poikilos/editablelistbox that is PEP8 for variable names, spacing & other things. It preserves the value on entry, generates names separately from values, & I've made other changes. It is currently CC BY-SA 4.0 due to the default license of stackoverflow. I would often suggest changing to CC0 but CC0 is having patent issues (when it comes to code) according to RedHat so to make it useful to the most people I won't for now. The MIT license seems permissive enough and compatible with GPL. Can you give me permission to change my release to the MIT License?

Comment: Good job @Poikilos. Yes, you can change the license to MIT. By the way, if you need help in the future on maintaining the repository (i.e. solving some issues), I can give you a hand. Best regards, David.

Answer (score 2):

No, tkinter doesn't support in-place editing of items in a listbox. Of course, if you don't really need a listbox, you can always stack labels or entry widgets on top of each other to get a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
# root.geometry('300x240')



sb = tk.Scrollbar(root)
sb.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.Y)
E1 = tk.Entry(root)
E1.pack()

mylist = [*range(15)]

v = tk.StringVar(value=mylist)
b1=tk.Listbox(root,activestyle='dotbox',yscrollcommand=sb.set,listvariable=v,selectmode='SINGLE')

sb.config(command=b1.yview)
# for i in range(1,15):
#     b1.insert(tk.END,i)
b1.pack()

def isfloat(s):
    try:
        return float(s)<float('inf')
    except:
        return False

def isInt(s):
    try:
        return int(s)<float('inf')
    except:
        return False

def set_entry_text(text):
    E1.delete(0,tk.END)
    E1.insert(0,text)


def set_item(event):
    text = E1.get()
    E1.delete(0,tk.END)
    index = b1.curselection()[0]
    b1.delete(index)
    b1.insert(index,text)
    print(v.get())

def set_item1(event):
    text = E1.get()
    E1.delete(0,tk.END)
    index = b1.curselection()[0]
    if isInt(text):
        mylist[index] = int(text)
    elif isfloat(text):
        mylist[index] = float(text)
    else:
        mylist[index] = text

    v.set(mylist)
    print(v.get())

def edit_item(event):
    text = E1.selection_get()
    # set_entry_text(text)
    E1.focus()


b1.bind('<Double-1>', edit_item)
E1.bind('<Return>',set_item1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add some explanation around your code and how it is different from the accepted answer. Just dumping code is not always the best.